# Installing Bitrix. Memory_limit value in php.ini. Editing the random.php file

Tags: php, web, memory, installation, bitrix

1. I tried to reinstall Bitrix for php version 7.4 and earlier. As a result I received the following window

[Invalid license](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikOc8.jpg)

that the license is not valid.

2. I tried to install Bitrix for php version 8.0 and higher. As a result, I encountered a problem similar to [Installing Bitrix. Forum](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic153708/) and  [Why is 1c Bitrix not installed on php 8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525698/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-1%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-8)? I am getting the following error - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\OSPanel\domains\technosale5\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php on line **117** Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0.

How to install any version of Bitrix?

There are 2 possible reasons (based on resources - [Installing Bitrix. Forum](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic153708/), [Why is 1c Bitrix not installed on php 8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525698/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-1%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-8), [Bitrix documentation](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/faq/8372/#top) ) - either the **memory_limit** value in the **php.ini** file is incorrectly specified, **or** an error in the function **$randomSequence = static::getBytes($length)**; on line **117**

I have the following memory_limit value

[previous memory limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SveZ.png)

What value should memory_limit be changed to?

Changed the memory_limit value to 8192M

[current memory_limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pZDQ.png)

and received

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDZSn.jpg)

Because in the error text refer (Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\OSPanel\domains\technosale5\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php on line **117** Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0 ) to the following line

```
$randomSequence = static::getBytes($length);
```

(line **117**)

then I provide the getBytes function (in the same file D:\OSPanel\domains\technosale5\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php)

```
public static function getBytes($length)
{
    $backup = null;

    if ($length <= 0)
    {
        $length = 1;
    }

    if (static::isOpensslAvailable())
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong);
        if ($bytes && strlen($bytes) >= $length)
        {
            if ($strong)
                return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
            else
                $backup = $bytes;
        }
    }

    if (file_exists('/dev/urandom'))
    {
        if ($file = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))
        {
            $bytes = @fread($file, $length + 1);
            @fclose($file);
            if ($bytes && strlen($bytes) >= $length)
            {
                return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($backup && strlen($backup) >= $length)
    {
        return substr($backup, 0, $length);
    }

    $bytes = '';
    while (strlen($bytes) < $length)
    {
        $bytes .= static::getPseudoRandomBlock();
    }

    return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
}
```

and in general I provide the above file

```
<?php
namespace Bitrix\Main\Security;

class Random
{
    const RANDOM_BLOCK_LENGTH = 64;
    // ToDo: In future versions (PHP >= 5.6.0) use shift to the left instead this s**t
    const ALPHABET_NUM = 1;
    const ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER = 2;
    const ALPHABET_ALPHAUPPER = 4;
    const ALPHABET_SPECIAL = 8;
    const ALPHABET_ALL = 15;

    protected static $alphabet = array(
        self::ALPHABET_NUM => '0123456789',
        self::ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        self::ALPHABET_ALPHAUPPER => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        self::ALPHABET_SPECIAL => ',.#!*%$:-^@{}[]()_+=<>?&;'
    );

    /**
     * Returns random integer with the given range
     *
     * @param int $min The lower bound of the range.
     * @param int $max The upper bound of the range.
     * @return int
     * @throws \Bitrix\Main\SystemException
     */
    public static function getInt($min = 0, $max = \PHP_INT_MAX)
    {
        if ($min > $max)
        {
            throw new \Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException(
                'The min parameter must be lower than max parameter'
            );
        }

        $range = $max - $min;

        if ($range == 0)
            return $max;

        if ($range > \PHP_INT_MAX || is_float($range))
        {
            throw new \Bitrix\Main\SystemException(
                'The supplied range is too great'
            );
        }

        $bits = static::countBits($range) + 1;
        $length = (int) max(ceil($bits / 8), 1);
        $filter = pow(2, $bits) - 1;
        if ($filter >= \PHP_INT_MAX)
            $filter = \PHP_INT_MAX;
        else
            $filter = (int) $filter;

        do
        {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(self::getBytes($length)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter;
        }
        while ($rnd > $range);

        return ($min + $rnd);
    }

    /**
     * Returns random (if possible) alphanum string
     *
     * @param int $length Result string length.
     * @param bool $caseSensitive Generate case sensitive random string (e.g. `SoMeRandom1`).
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getString($length, $caseSensitive = false)
    {
        $alphabet = self::ALPHABET_NUM | self::ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER;
        if ($caseSensitive)
        {
            $alphabet |= self::ALPHABET_ALPHAUPPER;
        }

        return static::getStringByAlphabet($length, $alphabet);
    }

    /**
     * Returns random (if possible) ASCII string for a given alphabet mask (@see self::ALPHABET_ALL)
     * @param int $length Result string length.
     * @param int $alphabet Alphabet masks (e.g. Random::ALPHABET_NUM|Random::ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER).
     * @param bool $requireAll Required chars from all the alphabet masks.
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getStringByAlphabet($length, $alphabet, $requireAll = false)
    {
        $charsetList = static::getCharsetsforAlphabet($alphabet);

        if($requireAll && count($charsetList) > 1)
        {
            return static::getStringByArray($length, $charsetList);
        }
        else
        {
            return static::getStringByCharsets($length, implode("", $charsetList));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns random (if possible) string for a given charset list.
     *
     * @param int $length Result string length.
     * @param string $charsetList Charset list, must be ASCII.
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getStringByCharsets($length, $charsetList)
    {
        $charsetVariants = strlen($charsetList);
        $randomSequence = static::getBytes($length);

        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $randomNumber = ord($randomSequence[$i]);
            $result .= $charsetList[$randomNumber % $charsetVariants];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * This function places chars from every charset into the result string randomly.
     * @param int $length Result string length.
     * @param array $charsetList Array of charsets.
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getStringByArray(int $length, array $charsetList): string
    {
        $count = count($charsetList);

        // take strlen() out of the cycle
        $charsets = [];
        foreach ($charsetList as $charset)
        {
            $charsets[] = [$charset, strlen($charset)];
        }

        $randomSequence = static::getBytes($length);

        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += $count)
        {
            shuffle($charsets);

            for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
            {
                $randomNumber = ord($randomSequence[$i + $j]);

                $charset = $charsets[$j][0];
                $charsetVariants = $charsets[$j][1];
                $result .= $charset[$randomNumber % $charsetVariants];

                if (($i + $j + 1) == $length)
                {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns random (if possible) byte string
     *
     * @param int $length Result byte string length.
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getBytes($length)
    {
        $backup = null;

        if ($length <= 0)
        {
            $length = 1;
        }

        if (static::isOpensslAvailable())
        {
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong);
            if ($bytes && strlen($bytes) >= $length)
            {
                if ($strong)
                    return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
                else
                    $backup = $bytes;
            }
        }

        if (file_exists('/dev/urandom'))
        {
            if ($file = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))
            {
                $bytes = @fread($file, $length + 1);
                @fclose($file);
                if ($bytes && strlen($bytes) >= $length)
                {
                    return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($backup && strlen($backup) >= $length)
        {
            return substr($backup, 0, $length);
        }

        $bytes = '';
        while (strlen($bytes) < $length)
        {
            $bytes .= static::getPseudoRandomBlock();
        }

        return substr($bytes, 0, $length);
    }

    /**
     * Returns pseudo random block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getPseudoRandomBlock()
    {
        global $APPLICATION;

        if (static::isOpensslAvailable())
        {
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(static::RANDOM_BLOCK_LENGTH);
            if ($bytes && strlen($bytes) >= static::RANDOM_BLOCK_LENGTH)
            {
                return substr($bytes, 0, static::RANDOM_BLOCK_LENGTH);
            }
        }

        $bytes = '';
        for ($i=0; $i < static::RANDOM_BLOCK_LENGTH; $i++)
        {
            $bytes .= pack('S', mt_rand(0,0xffff));
        }

        $bytes .= $APPLICATION->getServerUniqID();

        return hash('sha512', $bytes, true);
    }

    /**
     * Checks OpenSSL available
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected static function isOpensslAvailable()
    {
        static $result = null;
        if ($result === null)
        {
            $result = (
                function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')
                && strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== "win"
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns strings with charsets based on alpabet mask (see $this->alphabet)
     *
     * Simple example (now arrays!):
     * <code>
     * echo $this->getCharsetsforAlphabet(static::ALPHABET_NUM|static::ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER);
     * //output: 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
     *
     * echo $this->getCharsetsforAlphabet(static::ALPHABET_SPECIAL|static::ALPHABET_ALPHAUPPER);
     * //output:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.#!*%$:-^@{}[]()_+=<>?&;
     *
     * echo $this->getCharsetsforAlphabet(static::ALPHABET_ALL);
     * //output: 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.#!*%$:-^@{}[]()_+=<>?&;
     * </code>
     *
     * @param string $alphabet Alpabet masks (e.g. static::ALPHABET_NUM|static::ALPHABET_ALPHALOWER).
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getCharsetsForAlphabet($alphabet)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach (static::$alphabet as $mask => $value)
        {
            if ($alphabet & $mask)
            {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of bits needed to represent an integer
     *
     * @param int $value Integer value for calculate.
     * @return int
     */
    protected static function countBits($value)
    {
        $result = 0;
        while ($value >>= 1)
            $result++;

        return $result;
    }

}
```

I would like help editing the random.php file

Comment: Why do you want to edit that file? Anything not working if you **do** edit the file?

Comment: @NicoHaase see the last screenshot, error text - the file and the line where the error occurred are indicated there - **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\OSPanel\domains\technosale5\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php on line 117 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0**

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share all details **in text form**. That sounds like a horrible memory leak in your software - 17 GB are way more than a common application should use

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing Bitrix24 on Virtual Machine, it comes with all features it needs to run.

Currently i have sites working on **PHP 7.4** and **8.0** versions and don't see any problems so its not PHP version related. Also **8GB** memory should be enough to create dev workspace.

There is not much choices where you can install bitrix without problems:

- Windows: I've never used and i'll never use, you have to configure whole workspace manually.
- Virtual Machines: its easier to install and configure, but takes additional resources.
- Linux: even more easer to install and configure, lighter than vm, but there is requirement on OS, it should be **Centos7**, that's outdated.
- Containers: Haven't checked but going to, cause containers are getting more and more popular(it's in the middle of Vm and OS) and i think Bitrix won't be the exception. There is Centos official image on Dockerhub, and with the appropirate config, it should work.

And last advice: don't try to fit core to your workspace if you want to stay up to date, don't change anything. It's a large chain, whenever the core updates, there is a high chance that your site will crash.